# Text is invisible in some apps in El Capitan

Tags: macos, font

I've recently updated my Mac Mini to El Capitan and I am having problem with some of my apps: text is not displaying inside them.
I am facing this issue with at least this apps: GitHub for Mac:
[image]
Finder (folder names at the left panel and tags are empty) and Mail app
[image]

I thought that it can be the font issue, so I tried to go to the Fonts app and remove all duplicates, remove all fonts with errors and then reboot - no luck, still the same.

What can cause such a behavior?
It seems to be the system-wide issue (I tried to run Finder in Guest user and the issue was still present).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get this error on my 10.11 mac, try restarting the app, or restarting your computer, it usually fix these kind of problem. If you know how to reproduce this problem, you can report it into [Apple Bug Tracker](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Tried both restarting apps and computer, doesnt work.

Comment: @serge1peshcoff What version of OS X do you have?

Comment: last version, I guess

Comment: 10.11.3 (15D21) here it is

Comment: @serge1peshcoff Does it happen overtime or just sometimes?

Comment: It happens every time

Comment: Weird, sometimes it happens to my Mac Mini and fixed after reboot. If there are nothing very important onto your mac then you can try to reinstall OS X.